# Passing Safe Query Parameters with SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on a project that uses a HTML text input to retrieve data from a SQLite database.
The idea goes like this : the user types string representing a product number and I look into my database for that string.

I have tried to make my query safe for SQL injection as suggested in this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/) because the data does not come from me.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT product_number FROM price_history WHERE product_number = %s';", (user_input, ))
```

However, when I try to execute my code, I get :

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: Why do you have a single quote after the %s?

Comment: I copy pasted the code from the tutorial and adjusted it to my database

Comment: The trailing ‘ needs to go

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra `'` after `%s`.

Read the first paragraphs of the [python docs on sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#module-sqlite3) that show the correct way to use placeholders.

`cursor.execute("SELECT product_number FROM price_history WHERE product_number = (?)", (user_input, ))` should work.